# C++ use `const int` as looping variable?

Tags: c++, conditional-compilation

I want to write code that compiles conditionally and according to the following two cases:

CASE_A:

```
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i){
        // do something...
    }
```

CASE_B: ( == !CASE_A)

```
    {
        const int i = 0;
        // do something...
    }
```

That is, in case A, I want to have a normal loop over variable `i` but, in case B, i want to restrict local scope variable `i` to only a special case (designated here as `i = 0`).  Obviously, I could write something along the lines:

```
    for(int i = (CASE_A ? 1 : 0); i <= (CASE_A ? 10 : 0); ++i){
         // do something
    }
```

However, I do not like this design as it doesn't allow me to take advantage of the `const` declaration in the special case B.  Such declaration would presumably allow for lots of optimization as the body of this loop benefits greatly from a potential compile-time replacement of `i` by its constant value.

Looking forward to any tips from the community on how to efficiently achieve this.

Thank you!

EDITS:

CASE_A vs CASE_B can be evaluated at compile-time.

`i` is not passed as reference

`i` is not re-evaluated in the body (otherwise `const` would not make sense), but I am not sure the compiler will go through the effort to certify that

Comment: From a practical perspective, it would be ideal if the solution fits into the overall semantics, e.g., through a `#define Smart_Loop(i) ...` macro that would be used as: `for(Smart_Loop(i)){ ... }`

Comment: Seriously, I bet in all cases that your little loop will unrolled or plain optimized out anyways, regardless of how you define it. And every competent compiler will be able to remove the `int i` if it you don't take its address anywhere. Same with `const int i`, it can only be removed if you don't take its address.

Comment: I speculate that the compiler should be able to optimize this case for you.  As such, you should write the code that is easiest to read and maintain later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming, you aren't over-simplifying your example, it shouldn't matter.  Assuming CASE_A can be evaluated at compile-time, the code:

```
for( int i = 0; i <= 0; ++i ) {
    do_something_with( i );
}
```

is going to generate the same machine code as:

```
const int i = 0;
do_something_with( i );
```

for any decent compiler (with optimization turned on, of course).

In researching this, I find there is a fine point here.  If `i` gets passed to a function via a pointer or reference, the compiler can't assume it doesn't change.  This is true even if the pointer or reference is `const`!  (Since the `const` can be cast away in the function.)

Comment: Well, I guess the question is: "Is it?."  The compiler would need to certify that `i` is not changed within the body of the loop, which may or may not be apparent given the sophistication of the code in there.

Comment: Then make your code simpler, readable by others and a compiler! That way it does know exactly what your doing, and can optimize it for you.

Comment: To be fair, anything that would have prevented the compiler from knowing `i` was going to change would have produced an error, had `i` been declared `const`.

Comment: @Daniel - Agree 100% on the principle!  But, in practice, this would mean writing `if(CASE_A){...x...}else{...same x...}` and this `x` may be 1000 lines, so I am not sure if writing it like this qualifies as "simpler"

Comment: @Chrys - I looked into things a bit more.  If the code contains calls to functions, and those functions use references or pointers, you are correct, the compiler can't make the optimization.  I've updated my answer accordingly.  Absent such calls, it should be able to optimize it as I described.

Comment: The question is, why is x, 1000 lines!!? If Anything is more than a few hundred lines of code, it should probably be abstracted to sub methods, the compiler can decide if it is worth in-lining (and most likely will in this case); therefore, you have clean code!

Comment: I compiled with g++ CASE_B into assembly (-S) for the 3 different options (a) `for(int i =0;i<=0; ++i){...}`, (b) `{const int i = 0; ...}` and (c) `for(int ii = 0; ii<=0;++ii){ const int i = ii; ...}`.  For optimization levels -O1 and above, they all gave the same code.  Thanks everyone for the discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be the obvious solution:

```
template<int CASE>
void do_case();

template<>
void do_case<CASE_A>()
{
  for(int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i){
    do_something( i );
  }
}

template<>
void do_case<CASE_B>()
{
  do_something( 0 );
}

// Usage
...
do_case<CURRENT_CASE>(); // CURRENT_CASE is the compile time constant
```

Comment: I understand the use of templates to nicely implement the compile-time disjunction. But would this result into the build-up of 2 separate `void do_something(const int i);` functions: the generic one and the specialized `i=0` variant?

Answer (score 1):

If your CASE_B/CASE_B  determination can be expressed as a compile time constant, then you can do what you want in a nice, readable format using something like the following (which is just a variation on your example of using the `?:` operator for the `for` loop initialization and condition):

```
enum {
    kLowerBound = (CASE_A ? 1 : 0),
    kUpperBound = (CASE_A ? 10 : 0)
};

for (int i = kLowerBound; i <= kUpperBound; ++i) {
    // do something
}
```

This makes it clear that the `for` loop bounds are compile time constants - note that I think most compilers today would have no problem making that determination even if the `?:` expressions were used directly in the `for` statement's controlling clauses.  However, I do think using enums makes it more evident to people reading the code.

Again, any compiler worth its salt today should recognize when `i` is invariant inside the loop, and in the `CASE_B` situation also determine that the loop will never iterate.  Making `i` `const` won't benefit the compiler's optimization possibilities.

If you're convinced that the compiler might be able to optimize better if `i` is `const`, then a simple modification can help:

```
for (int ii = kLowerBound; ii <= kUpperBound; ++ii) {
    const int i = ii;

    // do something
}
```

I doubt this will help the compiler much (but check it's output - I could be wrong) if `i` isn't modified or has its address taken (even by passing it as a reference). However, it might help *you* make sure that `i` isn't inappropriately modified or passed by reference/address in the loop.

On the other hand, you might actually see a benefit to optimizations produced by the compiler if you use the `const` modifier on it - in the cases where the address of `i` is taken or the `const` is cast away, the compiler is still permitted to treat `i` as not being modified for its lifetime. Any modifications that might be made by something that cast away the `const` would be undefined behavior, so the compiler is allowed to ignore that they might occur. Of course, if you have code that might do this, you have bigger worries than optimization.  So it's more important to make sure that there are no 'behind the back' modification attempts to `i` than to simply marking `i` as `const` 'for optimization', but using `const` might help you identify whether modifications are made (but remember that casts can continue to hide that).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure that this is what you're looking for, but I'm using this macro version of the vanilla FOR loop which enforces the loop counter to be `const` to catch any modification of it in the body

```
#define FOR(type, var, start, maxExclusive, inc) if (bool a = true) for (type var##_ = start; var##_ < maxExclusive; a=true,var##_ += inc) for (const auto var = var##_;a;a=false)
```

Usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FOR(type, var, start, maxExclusive, inc) if (bool a = true) for (type var##_ = start; var##_ < maxExclusive; a=true,var##_ += inc) for (const auto var = var##_;a;a=false)

int main()
{
    FOR(int, i, 0, 10, 1) {
        printf("i: %d\n", i);
    }

    // does the same as: 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("i: %d\n", i);
    }

    // FOR catches some bugs:
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        i += 10; // is legal but bad
        printf("i: %d\n", i);
    }

    FOR(int, i, 0, 10, 1) {
        i += 10; // is illlegal and will not compile
        printf("i: %d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```